# Getting the date-time of the last commit

Tags: git

I'm trying to get the date-time of the last commit with whitespaces:

```
   git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%cd --date=format:%d %b %Y
```

An exception is:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '%b': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Comment: Exercises: (a) How many words are there in the phrase "See spot run"? (I know this seems trivial, it's to prepare for the next two.) (b) How many words are there in `format:%d %b %Y`? (c) How many words does `--date` *expect* after the `=` sign? There are a few Git commands/options that do expect, or at least handle, more than one word, but is `--date` one of them?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work with double quotes (using git version 2.13.1.windows.1):

```
vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\git
> git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%cd --date=format:"%d %b %Y"
15 Jun 2017
```

It works in bash too:

```
vonc@voncavn7 MINGW64 /d/git/git (master)
$ git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%cd --date=format:"%d %b %Y"
15 Jun 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command will be helpful:

```
 git log -1 --format=%cd
```

Abow command will print the latest change date. The -1 shows one log entry (the most recent), for more details check this [link](http://schacon.github.io/git/git-show).